# How does python print() actually work when called concurrently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I was trying to learn python's threading and I found these result.  I was wondering how python's print() actually outputs to the console.

```
import threading
import time
def testing(name):
   print(name)
y = threading.Thread(target=testing, args=("y",))
y.start()
x = threading.Thread(target=testing, args=("x",))
x.start()
```

Output

```
yx
```

```
import threading
import time
def testing(name):
   print(name)
y = threading.Thread(target=testing, args=("y",))
y.start()
time.sleep(.001)
x = threading.Thread(target=testing, args=("x",))
x.start()
```

Output

```
y
x
```

Really my question is why isn't the output of the first one:

```
y
x
```

Comment: What you're really asking here isn't so much about "line space" (a.k.a., "newlines.") You're asking how `print(...)` is supposed to behave when called concurrently from more than one thread. I don't know the answer, but don't be surprised if it turns out that there are _no_ rules. Threads are a relatively new addition to Python (newer than `print`, anyway) It's entirely possible that nobody's gotten around to writing a spec for how `print(...)` should behave when called from multiple threads.

Comment: Ok updated the question.   It seems like print is somehow time based which is interesting.

Comment: As I understand it you are using multiple entry points (concurrently) to the same PyObject and you just get an output if the gates (entry points) are closed. So you need a little bit of time to execute your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `print()` outputs your string, followed by a newline character (aka "\n").

I suspect that the print() function contains two calls to a lower-level C function (e.g. [puts()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/puts.3.html)) that handles the actual transfer of characters to stdout.  The first `puts()` transfers your string's characters, and then the second call transfers the implicit newline character.

When you run two threads at (almost) the same time, the second thread's `print()` call may pre-empt the execution of the first thread's `print()` call between those two lower-level calls, so that you get this order of execution:

```
Thread 1:  puts("y")
Thread 2:  puts("x")
Thread 2:  puts("\n")
Thread 1:  puts("\n")
```

.... which results in the string "yx\n\n" printed to stdout, as you saw.

Adding the`time.sleep()` to your main thread causes the execution of the second thread's `print()` call to be delayed until after the first thread's `print()`-call has finished:

```
Thread 1:  puts("y")
Thread 1:  puts("\n")
// ~1mS of time-delay passes
Thread 2:  puts("x")
Thread 2:  puts("\n")
```

... so in this scenario you get the output "y\nx\n" instead.